# How to find the exact occurrence of %s in a string in python

Tags: python

I have some SQL strings from where I want to find how many times the character **%s** occurred.

**Example string:**

```
query_fetch_user = """select * from users where id=%s and email LIKE '%sayhello%' """
```

Here I want to get the exact count of %s only and I want to avoid the email part to be accounted for the count.

What I tried.

```
query_fetch_user.count("%s")
```

This is giving count as 2

```
count = start = 0
while True:
   start = query_fetch_user.find(sub, start) + 1
   if start > 0:
        count+=1
   else:
       print(count)
```

This also giving count as 2

But the actual count should be 1.

Comment: Could you print out those two results?

Comment: So you're trying to find only the occurrences of `%s` that will have values interpolated into them by the SQL engine? **Please make that clear in the question if so.** You're probably not going to do that easily without using the SQL tooling; see if there's a method that prepares a query for execution and takes the values later on. You've already seen the problem with a naïve approach, that some occurrences may be in non-interpolated text, and a regex would be extremely fragile.

Comment: we can use new string formatting ( use `{}` instead of `%` ) can you use it ?

Comment: Our problem is to recognize difference  between `%s` and `%WORD_WITH_S_CHARACTER_AT_FIRST%` @AntonvBR

Comment: I know, but we still have problem in formatting string @AntonvBR

Comment: @ArashHatami OP is asking for counts. I don't see any information about formatting here.

Comment: If I've correctly understood the problem you're actually trying to solve (again, **please clarify what that is**), why not try executing the query *without* supplying any values to interpolate? For example, running that query in `sqlite3` would give `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.` The downside of this is that the query will be executed if it has no bindings.

Comment: why don't you use regex if you want to match a particular pattern

Comment: @AmirNaimi a regex would be very fragile, it's not a tool well-suited to complex parsing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. The exact reason I am doing this is to make sure that total parameter supplied is matching with total %s count

Comment: Right, then my question would be: **why are you doing that?** Your SQL library will tell you for sure if the count doesn't match, as my comment above shows for `sqlite3`. Please give some context, this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) at the moment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. It will throw an error saying parameter count doesn't match the placeholder count. But I don't want to get the error and then find out the issue. I need to make sure queries are correct before execution

Comment: Again, **why?** The only good general way to test that a query will work is to *execute the query*, and you should be handling any errors when that occurs anyway. See https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp; this is a common idiom in Python. Note also that placeholders like `%d` can also appear, which you wouldn't count.

Comment: @Arount yet again, **the placeholder and wildcard are in an SQL query**. This is **not** general Python string formatting. The query the OP shows would require two parameters if used with `%`, but only one when executed as a query.

Comment: *"for some reason"* - oh, for pity's... for **what** reason?! *"will be good"* -
 will it? How exactly? What if other placeholders (e.g. `%d`, which I think some libraries do use) appear? I won't waste further time on this, but you should really reconsider your approach. I'd also strongly recommend you rewrite the question to clarify **what you're trying to do** *before* the details of **how you're trying to do it**; the calibre and relevance of answers you've received hopefully demonstrates clearly why the current revision isn't helping you out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. In Python for all we can use %s.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. My ultimate aim is to find the count of standalone %s characters in string

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this RegEx instead:

```
\B%s\b
```

It'll only match standalone words (symbols like `=` or `'` does not count towards that) and it does not break if it's on a new line, end of a line or end of the String. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pR0NGN/5).

Explanation:

```
\B - Starts where \b does not match - essentially to find where there is a non-word character in front of the text (the start of the line, just after a linebreak, start of the String, period, space, etc)
%s - the String itself (in this case the literal `%s`)
\b - and ends at the word boundary - meaning where the word ends
```

Comment: It works, sure, but *for this string*; it's not a general solution, it doesn't *necessarily* discriminate between placeholders and wildcards.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it counts the amount of thes the single word %s shows up in the string, which is what OP aksed for

Comment: No, the OP wants to validate that the number of placeholders is equal to the number of values supplied ([I don't think that's a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058717/how-to-find-the-exact-occurrence-of-s-in-a-string-in-python#comment83090979_48058717), but still...). That is similar *in this case*, but not semantically identical.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's not what it says in the question

Comment: *"EDIT: The exact reason I am doing this is to make sure that total parameter supplied is matching with total %s count"* - also just *look* at what they're trying to parse. I agree they could and should have made the context clearer. Anyway, I've wasted enough time on this.

Comment: `I have the strings from where I want to find how many times the character %s occurred.` - what that is used for is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the point of a question on Stack Overflow is asking for a single problem. OP asked how you can count a given amount of references, not how to match the amount of input Strings with placeholders in a String.